# how to convert $.post form to $.ajax form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am  noob  at using jquery and ajax. I need to change the form from $.post to $.ajax .

```
   var disqus_config = function() {

            this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) {

                    $.post("sendnotification", { comment: comment.id, post: $post->id,author:$author->id}, function(result){

                            alert(result);

                    });

            }];
    };
```

I know I need to end something like here but I am stuck how to use post datas(comment,post,author) inside this function

```
   $.ajax({
         url: 'sendnotification',
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'query=' + query ,
         dataType: 'JSON',
         async: true,
         success: function(data){
            process(data)
         }
```

Thanks

Comment: Gotta ask, why bother? You aren't adding anything in the `$.ajax` call that can't be handled by `$.post`

Comment: Are those PHP variables ?

Comment: I use laravel , I am trying send to a controller. I am trying to get used to $.ajax form. now I get unexpected token synthax error ?

Comment: I use typeahead bootstrap also I will try to combine them both in one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same object literal you did for `$.post`, eg (gotta assume that's some PHP or something in there)

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'sendnotification',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { comment: comment.id, post: {$post->id}, author: {$author->id} },
     dataType: 'json',
     async: true,
     success: function(data){
        process(data)
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `dataType: 'JSON'` should be changed to  `dataType: 'json'`
Also, use the same data array as you used in your $.post variant.

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'sendnotification',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { comment: comment.id, post: $post->id,author:$author->id } ,
         dataType: 'json',
         async: true,
         success: function(data){
            process(data)
         }
});
```

Comment: Phil's answer was  very quick.